# uploading file on the server by clicking on generateFile and return a link to download jsf

Tags: jsf-2, facescontext

Jsf : how can i upload file to the server without having upload button .??

i have a genarate Excel File button.
how can i upload it to the server just by clikcing the Excel file Button and return a link to download file from the server ??

```
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
        ServletContext ctx = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
        String relativePath = ctx.getInitParameter("tempfile.dir");
        File file = new File(rootPath + File.separator + relativePath);
        if(!file.exists()) file.mkdirs();
        System.out.println("File Directory created to be used for storing files");
        ctx.setAttribute("FILES_DIR_FILE", file);
        ctx.setAttribute("FILES_DIR", rootPath + File.separator + relativePath);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        //do cleanup if needed
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException{
        DiskFileItemFactory fileFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        File filesDir = (File) getServletContext().getAttribute("FILES_DIR_FILE");
        fileFactory.setRepository(filesDir);
        this.uploader = new ServletFileUpload(fileFactory);
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
            throw new ServletException("Content type is not multipart/form-data");
        }

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write("<html><head></head><body>");
        try {
            List<FileItem> fileItemsList = uploader.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator<FileItem> fileItemsIterator = fileItemsList.iterator();
            while(fileItemsIterator.hasNext()){
                FileItem fileItem = fileItemsIterator.next();
                System.out.println("FieldName="+fileItem.getFieldName());
                System.out.println("FileName="+fileItem.getName());
                System.out.println("ContentType="+fileItem.getContentType());
                System.out.println("Size in bytes="+fileItem.getSize());

                File file = new File(request.getServletContext().getAttribute("FILES_DIR")+File.separator+fileItem.getName());
                System.out.println("Absolute Path at server="+file.getAbsolutePath());
                fileItem.write(file);
                out.write("File "+fileItem.getName()+ " uploaded successfully.");
                out.write("<br>");
                out.write("<a href=\"UploadDownloadFileServlet?fileName="+fileItem.getName()+"\">Download "+fileItem.getName()+"</a>");
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            out.write("Exception in uploading file.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.write("Exception in uploading file.");
        }
        out.write("</body></html>");
    }  enter code here
```

Comment: What prevents you from uploading the generated excel file to the server? What have you tried? Is there any error? Please don't expect people here to write the code for you.

Comment: i'm not asking for the  code , but the way or an example @Dat Nguyen